# Is it difficult to find my next transit flight at Dubai airport?

Tags: air-travel, transit, dxb

I have to travel to France and the transit will be on Dubai T3. Is it difficult to find gates and next flight there?

Comment: I've never seen an airport where this is complicated to find. How much transfer time do you got?

Comment: most probably 3hours. Is it difficult me to find the gates for the other flight? is the staff of the air port help for me to find out places?Actually I am very much worry on this.please let me know the process at the transferring also

Answer (score 4):

Three hours is plenty of time to transit Dubai airport. You will be fine. The only hold-up is usually when you disembark from the plane and go through security to enter the Terminal proper. However this is very fast and orderly.

When disembarking the plane, follow the signs for connections. Then go through Security into the Terminal building. Follow the signs to T3. Depending on your arrival Terminal this will include a short train ride. There aren't (IME) that many staff to direct you, but it's pretty obvious.

The main problems in Dubai airport are :

1. finding somewhere to sit (try the ends of each Terminal)
2. not spending money in any of the many shops
3. finding a luggage trolley

Answer (score 2):

I do not have experience with this specific airport, but 3 hours of transfer time are in general enough. If you have any concerns, there are a few things you can do to feel more comfortable

- Check the [terminal map](http://www.dubaiairport.com/en/passengers/airportguide/Documents/Terminal%203%20Maps.pdf) online. You can also copy them to your electronic devices, such that you can check them before arriving there.
- Check whether or not you have to claim and re-check your luggage. I can not tell for sure, but you can ask this at first check-in, which may depend on your further destinations.
- Check which gate you will depart. Normally, if you booked the flight on one ticket, you get all the boarding passes at first check-in, often containing gate numbers already. If not, you can ask at the counter, because normally they know. Then, upon arrival at the transit airport, quickly check for gate changes, look on your map, and try to find your gate.

Probably you will have two hours to relax after you found the gate. Try to find some nice meal, the restaurants are all indicated on the map.

Comment: Finding the right gate at DXB T3 will not be a problem, it's a long rectangle with logically ordered gates.  Finding what I'd call a nice meal, though, may be a problem...